# How to show element by timer?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a problem. I have an Activity with ViewPager which have some Fragments.

In my first Fragment I have some elements. Lets say an ImageView, TextView. How to make them visible by timer when you completely open the page of ViewPager?!

I used this code below in my MainActivity.java document to make that ImageView visible by timer but it works not as I expected. When i want to go to next page by scrolling and touch the screen ImageView dissapear. Why its happened?!

```
final ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.earth);
mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
mImageView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
       mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}}, 5000);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**My new edits:**

```
// Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
//open concrete page of ViewPager. setCurrentItem(index of page)
pager.setCurrentItem(1);

tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            //This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled, either as part of a program initiated smooth scroll or a user initiated touch scroll.
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            //This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                final ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.earth);
                mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                if (position == 0) {
                    mImageView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }

            //Called when the scroll state changes.
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

My Problem is conflict with TABS and ViewPager. When I use tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() i have conflict with pager.setCurrentItem(1); which shows concrete page when Activity first opened. In my case its shows 2-d page when Activity first opened but Tab shows that opened 1-st page. WHY?! How to solve this problem?!

Comment: It's not really clear what your asking for or what you've tried. If you post up some of your code so far, people will be able to help you with specific problems. Have a read of the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) under the asking section for advice on asking easy to answer questions.

Comment: @Rudi Hello! I updated my post a little bit! Can you check it again and do you have any ideas?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a timer. It would either fire too early, or too late during which your UI looks bad. Use the pager's events to know when to update your UI. For example, you can probably use `OnPageChangedListener`:

```
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // Now displaying page at position
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

       }
   };
```

Comment: Hello Greg Ennis! As I said I have ViewPager. I want to add some effects. Lets say when user scroll and open the page completely after some seconds ImageView will be visiable. I saw such things in some apps and it looks harmonically. So what setOnPageChangeListener can give me?! As i understand its all about state of Pages.

Comment: Exactly. Use the page change listener so you know when the user has changed to a new page, and start your animation then.

Comment: Hello Greg Ennis! I updated my post little bit, can you check it again?! I have some problems with TABS. When I use tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() i have conflict with pager.setCurrentItem(1); which shows concrete page when Activity first opened. In my case its shows 2-d page when Activity first opened but Tab shows that opened 1-st page. Do you know the reason of such thing?!

Comment: I must be on the wrong track since the other answer is the accepted answer

Comment: As a matter of fact i accepted both answers but i dont understand why only one of them was marked. Its sad! Anyway Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want setCurrentItem(1) ? I think its an off-by-1 error

Comment: Hello Greg! I have 3 pages in my ViewPager and when app will open I want to show users 2-d page. For thats why i used setCurrentItem(1) to show 2-d page. But i dont understand why its conflict with TABS.  =(